# When can I skip repeating the verb in a question?

Tags: phrase-usage, word-request, questions

I'm working on a text and struggle with a question I'm asking. Which of the following phrases is correct?

> 1. Or maybe you know something which we don’t **know**?

or

> 2. Or maybe you know something which we don’t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of them are *literally* correct.

The first one is a "complete" form of the second one. Rephrase, the second one is a more effective sentence, since English really prioritizes the effective use of words (no repetition of words used, if possible). Besides, by reading **only** the second one, you'll still know that *which we don't* refers to *which we don't know*.

If you like, you can also write them like this:

> Or maybe you know something we don’t? [without the word **which**]

Relative pronoun [e.g. *which, who, that, etc.*] is sometimes omitted in English sentences.

P.S.: Different rules count if you want to emphasize the word ***know***, which means you don't want "*that something we don't **know***" to be ignored in the sentence. Rephrase, **use** the word *know* (like the first sentence) if emphasizing it is necessary.